# rails can't migrate: "don't know how to build task VERSION:0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

First post on here so apologies for any noobity.
I'm working through the Lynda.com Ruby on Rails 5 Essential training on C9 and encountered a problem trying to migrate back down to 'VERSION:0' with this error message:

rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'VERSION:0' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in`perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in`'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in`require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in`load'
bin/rails:3:in `'

Any help or advice much appreciated

Comment: Try `VERSION=0` instead of `VERSION:0`

Comment: Ah man, silly mistake! Thanks  Máté

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing migration in Rails, you can do:

`rake db:migrate`, which will migrate your new migration to `database` and add them to `scheme.rb`.

You can also do `rake db:rollback`, which will *rollback* your **last** migration.

For *rollback* you can also do `rake db:rollback STEP=n`, which will roll you back `n` migrations where `n` is the number of recent migrations you want to rollback.

IF you want to *rollback* version of your migration you would apply the migration version as: `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` *(as @sjudge said in comments)*

You can also do `rake db:migrate:redo`.

There also some other migrations like:

```
rake db:migrate:redo STEP=n
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20080906120000
```